# Prevent string from splitting

Tags: output-formatting, gui-construction, grid-layouts, display, alignment

I have two elements of a grid:

```
Framed[Pane["this is a very long string", {130, 20}, 
  ImageSizeAction -> "Clip"]]
Framed[Pane["thisisaverylongstring", {130, 20}, 
  ImageSizeAction -> "Clip"]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Two questions:

1) How can I prevent the first string from being split at word boundaries?

2) Can I display instead the ends of strings, clipped from the left? Such that we have "..isaverylongstring" instead of "thisisaverylongs..." like

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Don't understand 2), but is `BaseStyle -> LineBreakWithin -> False` the answer for 1)?

Comment: @Kuba Apologies for not being clear. I mean like "..ylongstring" instead of "thisisaverylong..." I will edit the question. Thank you for 1) -- this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html)'s ability to align the string and convert it to [`Graphis`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphis.html), then combined with [Kuba's suggestion in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145717/44141) above, we can do it:

```
Framed@Pane[
  Graphics@Style[Text["thisisaverylongstring", {0, 0}, {1, 0}],20], 
   {130, 30}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
  BaseStyle -> LineBreakWithin -> False
 ]

Framed@Pane[
  Graphics@Style[Text["thisisaverylongstring", {0, 0}, {-1, 0}], 20], 
   {130, 30}, Alignment -> {Left, Center}, 
  BaseStyle -> LineBreakWithin -> False
 ]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Doesn't look like an ideal solution, but at least it works.

Answer (score 4):

The statement

```
Framed[Pane["thisisaverylongstring", {130, 20}, ScrollPosition -> {130, 20}]]
```

generates a pane in which the initial position is the bottom line, thereby showing the end of the multi-line string.  Even specifying the "Clip" option, I find that the panes are scrollable.

[image]

Comment: Addition of `BaseStyle -> LineBreakWithin -> False` makes this perfect solution. Note that `ScrollPosition -> 100`  is sufficient, the number just should be sufficiently large. Checked with version 11.1.1 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You are right. Almost. If the string fits the box (it is shorter and doesn't need to be clipped), the content is empty somehow... Try to increase the width to 200 or shorten the string.

Comment: @Stitch Yeah, `Pane` in this respect is still painful. :( Probably worth reporting as it doesn't look as expected behavior.